# After inactivity, TcpClient can't read/write on Azure Worker Role

Tags: c#, azure, tcpclient, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role listening to device connections. When a device connects to the listener I get `TcpClient` object and save it in a list. Here is the simplified code:

```
private List<TcpClient> connectors = new List<TcpClient>();
private TcpListener listener = null;

public async Task StartAsync()
{
    this.listener = new TcpListener(RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["DeviceListenerEndpoint"].IPEndpoint);
    this.listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            this.connectors.Add(tcpClient)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WorkerRole.Log(ex); // This method logs the exception
        }
    }
}
```

I have another Task running in the worker role. This task is to communicate with devices every X minutes, it uses the `connectors` list to send data to the devices. For each `TcpClient` I use my `DeviceConnector` class to communications:

```
public TcpClient TcpClient { get; private set; } = null;
private NetworkStream networkStream = null;

public DeviceConnector(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    this.TcpClient = tcpClient;
    this.networkStream = this.TcpClient.GetStream();
}

private async Task StartReadingAsync()
{
    int numberOfReadBytes = 0;
    string str = string.Empty;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            numberOfReadBytes = await this.networkStream.ReadAsync(this.readBuffer, 0, ConnectorConstants.ConnectorBufferSize, this.readingCancellation.Token);
            if (numberOfReadBytes > 0)
            {
                // Process the data
            }
        }
        catch { /* catch the exception */ }
    }
    while (this.TcpClient.Client.Connected);
}

public async Task WriteAsync(byte[] bytes)
{
    await this.networkStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

When I use Azure Emulator to run the worker role in my laptop I works well, but when I publish it on the cloud it doesn't works. The device connects but after a few minutes the task can't send data. To solve this problem have to send one byte every 30 seconds (I didn't check the max time):

```
private bool keepAlive = false;
private async Task KeepConnectorAliveAsync()
{
    this.keepAlive = true;
    while (this.keepAlive)
    {
        await this.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 0 });
        await Task.Delay(30000);
    }
}
```

I added `this.KeepConnectorAliveAsync()` in the end of the constructor and `this.keepAlive = false` at the beginning of `StartReadingAsync()` method.

And this is my question: **Is there any way to keep the connection alive/active without sending data periodically?**

Thank you.

Comment: I have a [blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html). In short, sending data is the solution most likely to work in every scenario.

Comment: After reading your blog post, I think I will keep the code like this for awhile. Thank you.